# Read different values from Excel file every time when test case runs

Tags: selenium, junit

I have create a excel file with some codes and I am using RepeatRule class to execute my test case 100 times in one class. I need to use different 100 codes every time the test will run rather than using the same code again and again. Below is my code

```
@Test

@Repeat(2)

public void Test() throws Exception {

    Success.setUp();
    Success.allowcokkies();


        //Success.Ecoomerecemain();
    File source = new File("/Users/test/Downloads/Voucher-codes.xlsx");
    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(source); // Read Excel Data
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(input);

    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    int noOfColumns = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

        System.out.println(noOfColumns);
        String[] Headers = new String[noOfColumns];
        int j=0;
        Headers[j] = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).getStringCellValue();
        Success.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"code\"]")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());// Enter Coupon
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    @After
            public void testdown()
    {
 Success.getDriver().quit();
```

This is repeat class code:
    public class RepeatRule implements TestRule {

```
public static class RepeatStatement extends Statement {
    private final Statement statement;
    private final int repeat;

    public RepeatStatement(Statement statement, int repeat) {
        this.statement = statement;
        this.repeat = repeat;
    }

    @Override
    public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
        for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
            statement.evaluate();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public Statement apply(Statement statement, Description description) {
    Statement result = statement;
    Repeat repeat = description.getAnnotation(Repeat.class);
    if (repeat != null) {
        int times = repeat.value();
        result = new RepeatStatement(statement, times);
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

How can I read different codes every time while using Repeat rule?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is a JUnit 5 parameterized test. Save your Excel sheet as csv and use the following test method:

```
  @ParameterizedTest
  @CsvFileSource(resources = "/Users/test/Downloads/Voucher-codes.csv", numLinesToSkip = 1)
  void testVoucher(String coupon) {
...
    Success.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"code\"]")).sendKeys(coupon);// Enter Coupon
...
  }
```

Parameterized tests are possible with JUnit 4 as well. An example is described in the [JUnit Wiki](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests). You can even use the Excel sheet as a data provider with your POI code.

Another solution would be using `@BeforeEach`, where you could update a coupon field `couponIndex` in your test class and access the right row by the value of this field.

```
        Success.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"code\"]")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(couponIndex).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());// Enter Coupon
```

I would recommend using a parameterized test.

Comment: Where I can use this method in Repeat rule?

Comment: I edited my answer. Changing your repeat role does not solve your problem. You are using 0 as a row index in every repitition. You have to change that in your test class.

Comment: I tried it and it is not working for me. could you please let me know how Can I get solution of my problem?

Comment: I am getting error while using this         Success.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"code\"]")).sendKeys(sheet.getRow(couponIndex).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());// Enter Coupon
what is couponindex in this?

Comment: As stated above, you will have to add this as a field to your test class and update the value in each repetition.

Comment: How can do this? Please share the code so I can run.